# CSS: how to align center-to-center horizontally the labels and the fields?

Tags: css, alignment

I have this [page](http://www.tirengarfio.com/rs2/web/index.php).

How do I horizontally align center-to-center the labels and the fields?

Regards

Javi

Comment: It's pretty tricky to determine to work out what you mean by "center-to-center horizontally", we could guess, but maybe try posting a picture of what you require it'd be easier to help, you'll probably have more success on http://doctype.com

Comment: Get rid of `main.css` (with those nasty CSS reset) and it'll be aligned correctly. You only have to set the font yet.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to simply add `padding-top` to the labels.

There's no inherent way in CSS of expressing the relative alignment of two elements, but just establishing good margins and padding is almost always sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to do it is with JavaScript.

http://www.nealgrosskopf.com/tech/thread.php?pid=37

Comment: Ahh, I thought you were talking about the content boxes.  But hey, still useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#contenedor_formularios label{
padding-top:4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

line-height is the best option when you need to vertical-align text (non-wrapping text, that is).

So, i tested it on firebug and adding line-height:20px to the label element seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best way to wrap the label in a span or div like the following:

```
<span style="display: inline; padding-top:4px; margin-right: 10px; float: left;">
<label for="email">Email Address</label>
</span>
```